# Вынести в отдельную функцию задание стилей объекта

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сейчас на странице есть несколько объектов, имеющих класс .foo. При клике на любой из этих объектов блок #bar меняет свое положение.

```
$(function() {
  $('.foo').click(function(){
    var foo_top  = $(this).position().top;
    var foo_left = $(this).position().left;

    $('#bar').offset({top: foo_top + 10, left: foo_left + 10});
  });
});
```

Т.к. код разрастается, хочется задание стилей сделать отдельной функцией. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "Декодированием"?

Comment: Оформление этого объекта на странице - задание его координат, размеров. Не очень удобное слово, но лучше не придумал.

Comment: Это называется ЗАДАНИЕ СТИЛЕЙ :)

Comment: Поправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тогда так:

```
function setStyle(event){
  var foo_top  = $(this).position().top;
  var foo_left = $(this).position().left;
  $('#bar').offset({top: foo_top + event.data.top, left: foo_left + event.data.left});
}
$(function() {
  $('.foo').on('click', {top: 10, left: 10}, setStyle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Так что ли?:

```
function setStyle(){
 var foo_top  = $(this).position().top;
 var foo_left = $(this).position().left;
 $('#bar').offset({top: foo_top + 10, left: foo_top + 10});
}
$(function() {
  $('.foo').click(setStyle);
}
```

Comment: Минус этого подхо лишь в невозможности передать параметры ф-ции setStyle но эту проблему можно решить использую ф-цию обёртку...

Comment: [Не взлетает](http://jsfiddle.net/Persio/Wpmew/1/). Что я делаю не так?

Comment: потому что у тов. @Rules скобки в ответе недоставлены, а я просто скопипастил, и строка `left: foo_top + 10` должна выглядеть так: `left: foo_left + 10` - это уже у вас в вопросе ошибочка.

Comment: @Spectre, ошибку поправил. Гадаю, где скобок не хватает.

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ!!! [спойлер](http://jsfiddle.net/EytK5/1/)